# Colouring separate variables in plot()

Tags: r, plot, colors

I'm using the rethinking package making a residual plot, plotting residuals for ASD and TD children against verbal IQ from a map model.

```
m3.2 <- map(
alist(
  ADOS ~ dnorm(mu, sigma),
  mu <- a + bV*VerbalIQ.s,
  a ~ dnorm(0, 10), 
  bV ~ dnorm(0, 1),
  sigma ~ dunif(0,10)
  ),
    data = ASDTD
)
```

Compute residuals for expected value at map for each child. Do this by subtracting the observed ados for each child from the predicted one, based on verbal IQ.

```
mu <- coef(m3.2)['a'] + coef(m3.2)['bV']*ASDTD$VerbalIQ.s
```

Compute residual for each child

```
m.resid <- ASDTD$ADOS - mu
m.resid
str(ASDTD)
```

## Residual plot

```
plot(ADOS ~ VerbalIQ.s, ASDTD, col= rangi2)
abline(m3.2)
```

Loop over children

```
 for (i in 1:length(m.resid)) {
   x <- ASDTD$VerbalIQ.s[i]
   y <- ASDTD$ADOS[i]
```

Draw line segment

```
lines(c(x,x), c(mu[i],y), lwd=0.5, col = col.alpha("black", 0.7))
}
```

When I run my code, I get both my groups residuals, ASD and TD, but I can't differentiate between them:
[Plot example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLhGb.png)

If I change my code in the plot, to specify the group to colour, I lose my mark (blue circle) for the other group

```
plot( col = ASDTD$ASD == 1)
```

like so:
[Second plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8b7FH.png)

I would like my plot to look like the first one, but just have my two groups coloured differently from each other so I can identify them. I have tried different solutions on here, but they only include one group and doesn't colour them, as you can see in my second plot.

I am not sure how to make this in ggplot because of my map model (as I said I'm using the rethinking package for my statistical model), so I would like suggestions specific to plot(), not ggplot.